# I have problems with unity android build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, build

sorry for bad English, I am Russian.
Before building my apk has 1 mb, when must have 50 or more.
When I install apk on device it not appear on main menu, therefore I can not open it. But I see this app in setting/application of my device.
When I build apk errors do not appear.
How to solve it? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what program you're using to write your code, but Microsoft has a lot of documentation for [publishing apps from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Take a look at the links at the end of this article. Do any of them help? I don't have any perspective into how folks search for documentation in their own languages, and I don't know how to help you find Russian documentation, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I can read documentation in English. Thank you, i will see if I find something among articles.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? The app doesn't install?

Comment: I make android build and it is building successful, but apk file has 1 mb, it is empty, do not include assets (scene, prefabs, sprites). When I build on PC build is working well.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem silly, did you add the scene to Build build settings?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html

like the scene should be a part of the build settings

Comment: Yes, I add scene to Build Settings.